# Why this SQL query does not work?

Tags: mysql, sql

I wrote this query but I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN INSERT
>   INTO `forum_topics_track` (`userid`, `topic_id`, `c' at line 3

I guess it is self explanatory but my goal is to check if the record exists and if it doesn't, to insert it.

```
IF NOT EXISTS 
                (SELECT * FROM `forum_topics_track` WHERE `userid` = '{$userid}' AND `topic_id` = '{$topic_id}') 
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO `forum_topics_track` (`userid`, `topic_id`, `category_id`) 
                VALUES ('{$topic_id}', '{$category_id}', '{$userid}')
            END;
```

Comment: There's no need to check anything first. In fact it's completely counterproductive!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A faster alternative would be to have a UNIQUE INDEX on `userid` and `topic_id`.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX forum_topics_track_ndx ON forum_topics_track(userid, topic_id);
```

Then you could do

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `forum_topics_track` (`userid`, `topic_id`, `category_id`) 
            VALUES ('{$topic_id}', '{$category_id}', '{$userid}');
```

which would always succeed (possibly doing nothing if the data already is there).

Or you could look into the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` trick.

Comment: Yeah this is the first thing I tried and it worked. Thank you and to the rest that answered my question.

Answer (score 1):

This is the wrong way to implement the logic.  If you want each user and topic to appear in `forum_topics_track` one time, then have the database enforce the constraint.  This is easy with a unique index or constraint:

```
create unique index unq_forum_topics_track_user_topic on forum_topics_track(user_id, topic_id);
```

Then, you can do an insert and ignore or handle the error:

```
INSERT INTO `forum_topics_track` (`userid`, `topic_id`, `category_id`) 
    VALUES ('{$topic_id}', '{$category_id}', '{$userid}')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE userid = VALUES(userid);
```

No `IF` is needed in the logic.  In fact, using `IF` just invites problems due to race conditions and doesn't really guarantee anything in the database.

Answer (score 0):

IF NOT EXISTS is a clause that is available to use in MS-SQL but not in MySQL. Please try following query.

```
INSERT INTO `forum_topics_track` (`userid`, `topic_id`, `category_id`) 
SELECT '{$topic_id}', '{$category_id}', '{$userid}'
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT * FROM `forum_topics_track` WHERE `userid` = '{$userid}' AND `topic_id` = '{$topic_id}'
)
```

Comment: You can't use a WHERE clause without a FROM clause. But you can fix it with a subquery in the FROM clause.

Comment: Hi Paul, I tested this query and it is working fine. FROM Clause will be required only if I try to run following part of query.

SELECT '{$topic_id}', '{$category_id}', '{$userid}'
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT * FROM `forum_topics_track` WHERE `userid` = '{$userid}' AND `topic_id` = '{$topic_id}'
)

Comment: I tested it on http://rextester.com (which is running MySQL 5.7), and to my surprise it worked. However it doesn't work on my local MariaDB 10.0.19. I'm pretty sure it also doesn't work on MySQL 5.6, but I have no installation here to test. And if you look at the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html), you will see, that `WHERE` cannot occur without `FROM`: "**[** FROM table_references [PARTITION partition_list] [WHERE where_condition] ... **]**". So while it works on MySQL 5.7 - This behaviour is not documented.

Comment: I found this in reference manual
 SELECT can also be used to retrieve rows computed without reference to any table.

For example:

mysql> SELECT 1 + 1;
        -> 2

You are permitted to specify DUAL as a dummy table name in situations where no tables are referenced:

mysql> SELECT 1 + 1 FROM DUAL;
        -> 2
(almost similar to oracle SQL)

Comment: That's true and i've used it many times. But there is no WHERE clause in that example.